# Is there a powerful alternative for Objective-C for iOS development

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, ios7

As an old C/C++, C#, Java, JS, PHP programer, I just couldn't get used to Objective-C. The reasons are obvious. I want to continue developing iOS applications and continue using Xcode storyboards. But I seriously need an alternative to Objective-C, is there any powerful tool or framework alternatives that could help me get away from Objective-C?

By powerful alternative, I mean useful enough to use most of the device methods/functions easily and has a lot of online resources, tutorials, examples on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would very, very strongly recommend that you get a good Objective-C book, or work through the Stanford iOS development course on iTunes U. Without Objective-C, you will get a lot less help with other languages, you won't be able to understand code samples, you won't understand the iOS documentation.

Comment: I have already gone through the Stanford course + another objective-c course + another ios course. Normally when learning a language I get familiar very quickly and don't require more tutorials. However I am still not comfortable with objective-c. Thank you for your recommendation anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://xamarin.com/ios - this allows you to write in C#. Personally I've used all those languages as well (other than C#) but actually prefer Objective-C.

Comment: Reason for prefering Objective-C?

Comment: I find it very readable and easy to write. But then I've used it since 1998 (with a long gap in the middle) so maybe it's simply I'm used to it.

Comment: Objective-C is also a more sturdy language than C# when it comes to developing for iOS. If you want to stick with Storyboards, then I would recommend getting comfortable with obj-c.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider RubyMotion - http://www.rubymotion.com

Comment: You can look for a code example with uses a storyboard: https://gist.github.com/aiwilliams/2710489